# Python Tkinter grid-geometry sticky setting not effective(?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm designing simple entry dialog in Python/Tkinter using the `grid` geometry, and getting some unexpected behavior.  When I start out with this code:

```
winAddNew = tk.Toplevel()
winAddNew.title('Add New Customer')
lblName = tk.Label(winAddNew,
                   anchor=tk.W,font=fntNormal,
                   text='Enter the complete name of the customer:')
entName = tk.Entry(winAddNew,
                   justify=tk.LEFT, font=fntNormal, width=20,
                   textvariable=ctrlNewCustomerName)
lblID = tk.Label(winAddNew,
                 anchor=tk.W,font=fntNormal,
                 text='Enter a unique three-character ID:')
entID = tk.Entry(winAddNew,
                 justify=tk.LEFT, font=fntNormal, width=8,
                 textvariable=ctrlNewCustomerID)
lblName.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=tk.W,padx=10,pady=(10,0))
entName.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=tk.W,padx=10,pady=(5,0))
lblID.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=tk.W,padx=(10,0),pady=10)
entID.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=tk.W,padx=(0,10),pady=10)
```

...this is how the rendered window looks on my machine (Windows 7, Python 2.7.3).  Note that the green lines aren't actually there, I'm just using them to lay out what I assume should be the positions of the rows and columns.

[image]

So far so good.  Now I want to set the `width` of `entName` up to `60`, to give more visible room to type in the customer name.  Because I have its `columnspan` set to `2`, and because every widget is set with `tk.W` for the `sticky` option, I'm expecting that increasing the width of `entName` would have no effect other than widening the entry widget itself, and widening the window accordingly.  All other widgets' positions relative to each other should stay the same -- right?

Nope.  Widening `entName` also causes `entID` to be pushed out away from `lblID`:

[image]

So what am I missing?  Why doesn't `entID` stay where it was?  And is there some way to make it stay in place, apart from blocking off row 2 into its own frame?

Comment: I think that ultimately, the grid also allows for some padding as well.  As you already said, putting it in it's own Frame is probably the most robust solution that you're gonna find.  Of course, you could try increasing the columnspan of your big entry as well, but I don't know if that'll really buy you much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you make the entry widget bigger, Tkinter has to allocate extra space to either column 0 or column 1. It does this according to the "weight" each column has.

Because you haven't explicitly set a weight, all columns get the default weight of zero. In your case, however, something has to grow. Tkinter chooses the first column if no columns have weight. This explains why entID gets pushed over -- the first column is made wider to accommodate the widget entry widget.

If you give column 1 a weight of 1, any extra space will be allocated to that column, leaving column 0 to be just wide enough to hold whatever is constraining that column (ie: any widgets that don't span columns).  You do this with the `grid_columnconfigure` command.

For example:

```
winAddNew.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Note that weight can be any positive integer; it represents a ratio. So, for example, if you set column 0 to 1 and column 1 to 2, column 1 will be given twice the amount of extra space that column 0 is given.

Tkinter does a poor job of documenting this behavior. The definitive documentation is in the Tcl/Tk man pages. Specifically, see [Grid Algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/grid.htm#M32) in the grid man page.

Comment: Bingo.  I've modified the weighting explicitly before with other displays, but didn't realize it still occurred implicitly by default.  Thanks very much!