# Tkinter: sticky won't stick properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, grid

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844173/tkinter-sticky-not-working-for-some-frames). In short, I'm having problems with sticky.

My code without the weights looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *; 


class calculator:

    #def update(self, 

    def __init__(self, window):
        """
        Constructor method.
        """

        self.toCompute = []; self.In = StringVar(); self.Out = StringVar();
        self.In.set("Hello"); self.Out.set("Hi there!");

        # Window title
        window.title("Logic Calculator");

        # The set of 5 frames.
        ioFrame = Frame(window, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=3); 
        ioFrame.grid(row=0, sticky=N+E+S+W, columnspan=2); 
        nwFrame = Frame(window); nwFrame.grid(row=1,column=0); 
        neFrame = Frame(window); neFrame.grid(row=1,column=1); 
        swFrame = Frame(window); swFrame.grid(row=2,column=0); 
        seFrame = Frame(window); seFrame.grid(row=2,column=1); 

        # Top 2 rows: the IO portion
        Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.In, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0, sticky=N+W);
        Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.Out).grid(row=1, sticky=S+E,columnspan=2);

        # Top left 2x2 Frame: [ ( | ) ][ T | F ]
        brlButton = Button(nwFrame, text='(', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        brrButton = Button(nwFrame, text=')', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        truButton = Button(nwFrame, text='T', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        falButton = Button(nwFrame, text='F', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        # Top right 2x2 Frame: [ AND | OOR ][ NND | NOR ]
        andButton = Button(neFrame, text='and', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        oorButton = Button(neFrame, text='oor', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        nndButton = Button(neFrame, text='nnd', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        norButton = Button(neFrame, text='nor', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        # Bottom left 2x2 Frame: [ SSO | IIF ][ NSO | NIF ]
        andButton = Button(swFrame, text='sso', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        oorButton = Button(swFrame, text='iif', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        nndButton = Button(swFrame, text='nso', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        norButton = Button(swFrame, text='nif', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        # Bottom right 2x2 Frame: [ EEQ | NEG ][ NEQ | === ]
        eeqButton = Button(seFrame, text='eeq', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        negButton = Button(seFrame, text='neg', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        neqButton = Button(seFrame, text='neq', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        comButton = Button(seFrame, text='=', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);


if __name__ == "__main__": # Only runs program if this specfic file is opened.

    window = Tk(); # The window
    calculator(window);
    window.mainloop();
```

However, this doesn't exactly look like what I want. I want the input line (the stuff inside iFrame) to have the `SUNKEN` relief stretched to the entire row/line. Further, I want the input to remain left-aligned (thus, `sticky=N+W`, though the `N` appears redundant in that but whatever). In addition, I want the output to be right-aligned.

Basically, the final picture should be something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGIJD.png).

Thanks for the help.

PS. I know I don't need semicolons in Python. I just like them lol.

Comment: don't use `;` in python

Comment: @SierraMountainTech But I want to. :p

Comment: I added an answer that corrects the formatting of your frame so your labels are set up correctly. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see an entry widget for an input line so I will just work with the stuff inside of `ioFrame`.

I am assuming yo want the label with the `SUNKEN` relief setting to stretch across the frame its in.

The way to accomplish this is to add a weight of 1 to the frames column the widget is in first by doing:

`ioFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)`

Then you need to change:

```
Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.In, relief=SUNKEN).grid(row=0, sticky=N+W)
```

To:

```
Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.In, relief=SUNKEN, anchor = W).grid(row=0, sticky=N+W+E)
```

By adding `anchor = W` to the creation of your widget we keep the textvariable of the label aligned to the left. and by changing the sticky to say `sticky = N+W+E` you tell python to stretch the widget to fit the cell up left and right.

One more thing. You might want to change the way you assign NSEW. Those constants only work if you are importing them with `*` or individually. You can write them differently to prevent any issues with the directional code if you change how you import by using quotes instead. IE: `sitcky = "nsew"`

Here is your code modified with the needed changes. I still think using `;` is pointless here.

```
from tkinter import *; 


class calculator:

    def __init__(self, window):

        self.toCompute = []; self.In = StringVar(); self.Out = StringVar();
        self.In.set("Hello"); self.Out.set("Hi there!");
        window.title("Logic Calculator")

        ioFrame = Frame(window, relief=GROOVE, borderwidth=3); 
        ioFrame.grid(row=0, sticky=N+E+S+W, columnspan=2)
        ioFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) 
        nwFrame = Frame(window); nwFrame.grid(row=1,column=0); 
        neFrame = Frame(window); neFrame.grid(row=1,column=1); 
        swFrame = Frame(window); swFrame.grid(row=2,column=0); 
        seFrame = Frame(window); seFrame.grid(row=2,column=1); 

        Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.In, relief=SUNKEN, anchor = W).grid(row=0, sticky=N+W+E);
        Label(ioFrame, textvariable=self.Out).grid(row=1, sticky=S+E,columnspan=2);

        brlButton = Button(nwFrame, text='(', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        brrButton = Button(nwFrame, text=')', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        truButton = Button(nwFrame, text='T', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        falButton = Button(nwFrame, text='F', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        andButton = Button(neFrame, text='and', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        oorButton = Button(neFrame, text='oor', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        nndButton = Button(neFrame, text='nnd', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        norButton = Button(neFrame, text='nor', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        andButton = Button(swFrame, text='sso', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        oorButton = Button(swFrame, text='iif', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        nndButton = Button(swFrame, text='nso', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        norButton = Button(swFrame, text='nif', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

        eeqButton = Button(seFrame, text='eeq', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=0);
        negButton = Button(seFrame, text='neg', height=2, width=10).grid(row=0,column=1);
        neqButton = Button(seFrame, text='neq', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=0);
        comButton = Button(seFrame, text='=', height=2, width=10).grid(row=1,column=1);

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    window = Tk();
    calculator(window);
    window.mainloop();
```