# Tkinter - expand frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have copied this code from the internet and I am twinkling it to fit my needs. I am trying now to make the frame on row=1 column=1 to expand through the screen by using the sticky='nswe'. However, no matter what I do, I can only see this frame at its minimum size. Can anyone help me out to fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import Azfunc

import os

LARGEFONT = ("Verdana", 35)

color_style = {"red": "#7E1B2A",
               "dark_red": "#3F0E15",
               "yellow": "#FFD100",
               "lavender": "#E1DCEB",
               "grey": "#F3F3F3",
               "dark_grey": "#6E6E7D"}  # todo fix this later. It is necessary to transform it in a


class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):

    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # __init__ function for class Tk
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.state('zoomed')
        topframe = tk.Frame(self, height=50, bg='black')
        topframe.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='we')

        left_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='blue', width=20)
        left_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='ns')

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        # main_frame.pack_propagate(0)
        main_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nswe")
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        # initializing frames to an empty array
        self.frames = {}

        # iterating through a tuple consisting
        # of the different page layouts
        for F in (StartPage, Page1, Page2):
            frame = F(main_frame, self)
            # initializing frame of that object from
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with
            # for loop
            self.frames[F] = frame

            # frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    # to display the current frame passed as
    # parameter
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


# first window frame startpage

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="green")
        # label of frame Layout 2

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        ## button to show frame 2 with text layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


# second window frame page1
class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page 1", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="StartPage",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # putting the button in its place
        # by using grid
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


# third window frame page2
class Page2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page 2", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 3 with text
        # layout3
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Startpage",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


class Page3(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page 2", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 3 with text
        # layout3
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Startpage",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


class Page4(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Page 2", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 2 with text
        # layout2
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page1))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

        # button to show frame 3 with text
        # layout3
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Startpage",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        # putting the button in its place by
        # using grid
        button2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)


# Driver Code
app = tkinterApp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15530923/16136190) help?

Comment: I added this piece of code, but nothing has changed!

Comment: Which piece of code did you add?

Comment: the grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1). The one mentioned in the article you linked on your first answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to provide a [example] of your code, so that others can run and test your code. This code could be drastically reduced while still demonstrating the problem, and it also doesn't run because of an import error. See [ask] and the [help] for more information on asking good questions.